# How to carry some codes in a variable?

Tags: php

I have a field in MySQL that contains following:

```
$a[]=5;
$a[]=3;
foreach($a as $n)
echo $n;
```

I want to be able to run this code in PHP. Want to help?

Comment: What does the field in MySQL contain exactly, the whole piece of php code? You could use `eval` but it's kinda dangerous..

Comment: I'm not sure I want to help, you could use `eval`... I never ever had to run a custom database stored code, what the heck are you doing?

Comment: I want to store my codes on my db and get them when i need :)

Comment: One case I've used it is to store little pieces of code, *only* for a dev environment. But, make sure you don't even create the table in production, and you don't export the code that runs it either (or you're very careful about restricting access to it)

Comment: yeah that was obvious.. but why??

Comment: because easier to edit codes when needed. thanks guys for reminders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval)

But the use of `eval()` comes with a lot of security risks. In most cases, the use of `eval()` is caused by failure in abstraction. I recommend that you rethink your design.

Comment: http://www.blog.highub.com/php/php-core/php-eval-is-evil/

Answer (score 0):

Dont store your code in DB, when you want to add it use `require_once` or `include_once` and have them in a file, it will be more flexible solution for you, when you will want to change something in code.